# How to set color to specific date in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

```
var active_dates1 = ["2017-04-02 00:00:00","2014-04-03 00:00:00","2014-04-01 00:00:00"];
    $('.datePick', this.$el).datepicker(

        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            for(let date1 of active_dates1){
            if (date.getTime() === new Date(date1).getTime()) {
                return { classes: 'activeClass' };
            }
            else {
                return {};
            }
            }

        }
    });
```

when i am using the upper code ,so it is changing the color of all dates.But I want to change the color of specific date.

Comment: where you are applying condition that on which date color will chnage ? and i dont know why but your code is seems to be wrong

Comment: what dates are available in active_dates1  for that I have to change the color

Comment: your code and explanation is not clear please make some changes in code and question to make this question more clear

Comment: date which is avilable in the array 'active_dates1', for them I have to change the color like red or blue what ever....so can you tell me how can I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use simple if condition and notice that both for variable and function parameter name are same that cause problem.
i assumed that your parameter is string.

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    for (let item of active_dates1) {
       if(item == date)
          return { classes: 'activeClass' };
       else // return empty object or or somthing else
          return {};
    }
}
```

according to [jquery ui documantion](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) returned object must be an array. first literal is true/false for enable or disable date selection and the second one is CSS class.
 so your final code is somthing like this

```
 if (date.getTime() === new Date(date1).getTime()) {
     return [true,'activeClass'];
 }
 else {
     return [true,''];
 }
```

Comment: thanks for ur comment,Now it is working. I have edited my question.Now I am passing more than value,but it is changing the color of only first value of array

Comment: changed method result type according to documentations